# cordova zeroconf how support?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cordova, zeroconf

I'm using `bonjour` to serve my service 
running on my server

```
var test= bonjour.publish({ name: "abcd", type: 'http', port: settings.server.port });
test.start();
```

running on the client:

```
function onDeviceReady() {

  console.log('in deviceready')
  var zeroconf = cordova.plugins.zeroconf;
  console.log(zeroconf)

  zeroconf.watch('abcd._http._tcp.local.', function (result) {
    console.log('in zeroconf')
    var action = result.action;
    var service = result.service;
    if (action == 'added') {
      console.log('service added', service);
    } else {
      console.log('service removed', service);
    }
  });
  console.log("test")
}
```

But I don't get any response/success at my `zeroconf.watch` method. I added the needed plugin but nothing works...

Answer (score -1):

I's work for me:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function onDeviceReady() {
        ZeroConf.watch('_http._tcp.local.', function(resp){
            document.getElementById("zeroconf2").innerHTML = resp;
        });
    }
    function onLoad() {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    }
    onLoad();
</script>
```

And put this line to config.xml

```
<gap:plugin name="cordova-zeroconf-plugin" source="npm" />
```